# Some sharing options not showing above answer box

Tags: bug, design, browser-support

Some sharing options above the answer box don't show up for me, Here is what I'm running:

```
Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86
Windows 10 insider build th2_release 10586 core
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes, I am logged in @rene .

Comment: You are using some form of ad blocking.  Since Facebook, etc. could track you if you use those links, they're blocked.